# How do I fix return error I'm getting from this generator code?

Tags: c#, random

Trying to randomly generate and save village scenarios in a list for a game project with the following code but I keep getting "'Village.StandardVillage()': not all code paths return a value" error. I've tried fixing it a couple of different ways but end up with other errors. So far this is what I have:

```
public class Village
{
    public string name;
    public int setLandscape;
    public int setTool1;
    public int setTool2;

    public Village(string name, int setLandscape, int setTool1, int setTool2)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.setLandscape = setLandscape;
        this.setTool1 = setTool1;
        this.setTool2 = setTool2;
    }
    private static List<Village> VisitedVillages = new List<Village>();
    public static Village StandardVillage()
    {
        var randVillage = new Random();
        string name = GenerateCoolVillageName();
        var village = new Village( //make random village
            name: name,
            setLandscape: randVillage.Next(1, 5),
            setTool1: randVillage.Next(1, 3),
            setTool2: randVillage.Next(1, 3)
        );
        VisitedVillages.Add(village); //store village in ram so it can be revisited later
        VisitVillage(
            village.setLandscape,
            village.setTool1,
            village.setTool2
        );
    }
    internal static string GenerateCoolVillageName()
        => $"Village {VisitedVillages.Count + 1}";
    private static void VisitVillage(int setLandscape, int setTool1, int setTool2)
    {
        string villageOptions;
        do
        {
            if (setLandscape == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("       (________________)");
                Console.WriteLine("        |              |");
                Console.WriteLine("        |  []  []  []  |");
                Console.WriteLine(" _______|____          |");
                Console.WriteLine(" |          |  []  []  |       ");
                Console.WriteLine(" | { }  { } |          |    _I_____");
                Console.WriteLine(" |          |  []  []  |   /_______\\");
                Console.WriteLine(" | { }  { } |          |   | [] [] |");
                Console.WriteLine("_|          |  []  []  |___| [] [] |_");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            }
            if (setLandscape == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("               xXxXxXxXxXxXx ");
                Console.WriteLine("               |           | ");
                Console.WriteLine("               | |}{| |}{| | ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ____________  |           | ");
                Console.WriteLine(" |          |  | |}{| |}{| |     _I_____");
                Console.WriteLine(" |  []  []  |  |           |    /_______\\");
                Console.WriteLine(" |          |  | |}{| |}{| |  _ | [] [] |");
                Console.WriteLine("_|  []  []  |__|           |__|_| [] [] |_");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");
            }
            if (setLandscape == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("                {_{_{_{_}_}_}_}");
                Console.WriteLine("                /             \\");
                Console.WriteLine("               /_______________\\");
                Console.WriteLine("   _I_____     |               |");
                Console.WriteLine("  /_______\\    |  {} {} {} {}  |");
                Console.WriteLine("  | [] [] |    |               |  (__)");
                Console.WriteLine("xX| [] [] |Xx__|  {} {} {} {}  |___()_");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            }
            if (setLandscape == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("                     {____________}");
                Console.WriteLine("                     |            |");
                Console.WriteLine(" __________________  | [}{]  [}{] |");
                Console.WriteLine(" |                |  |            |");
                Console.WriteLine(" | [] [] [] [] [] |  | [}{]  [}{] | ____");
                Console.WriteLine(" |                |  |            | |__|");
                Console.WriteLine("_| [] [] [] [] [] |__| [}{]  [}{] |_|  |");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
            }
            if (setTool1 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1) Speak to someone in charge");
            }
            if (setTool1 == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1) Ask about local rumors");
            }
            if (setTool2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2) Go to the local guild hall");
            }
            if (setTool2 == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2) Go to the local tavern");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("0) Exit to map");

            villageOptions = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            if (villageOptions == "1" && setTool1 == 1)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("The elderman of the village greets you cheerily.");
            }
            if (villageOptions == "1" && setTool1 == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A local indulges you.");
                Console.WriteLine("\"I hear the local tavern cooks a mean birdpie.\"");
            }
            if (villageOptions == "2" && setTool2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You approach the local guild hall. The sign on the building reads:");
                Console.WriteLine("\"Jiu-jitsu Guild\"");
            }
            if (villageOptions == "2" && setTool2 == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You approach the local tavern, the taste of whiskey already on ");
                Console.WriteLine("your lips.");
            }
            if (villageOptions == "0")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                return;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

        }
        while (villageOptions != "0");
    }
    internal static void RevisitAVillage()
    {
        int count = VisitedVillages.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You currently haven't visited any villages");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to map");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Which village do you wanna revisit?");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisitedVillages.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + 1);
            Console.Write(") ");
            Console.WriteLine(VisitedVillages[i].name);

        }
        string picked_village_input = Console.ReadLine();
        int input_as_int = int.Parse(picked_village_input) - 1;
        var village = VisitedVillages[input_as_int];

        Console.Clear();

        VisitVillage(
            village.setLandscape,
            village.setTool1,
            village.setTool2
            );

        bool exitMap = true;
        while (exitMap == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is your map");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("0) Revisit a town");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Search for a new location");

            string newLocation = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            if (newLocation == "0")
            {
                Village.RevisitAVillage();
            }
            if (newLocation == "1")
            {
                Village.StandardVillage();
            }
            if (newLocation == "2")
            {
                exitMap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually **no** code path in `StandardVillage()` does return **anything**. `return` a `Village` in it or change the return type to `void`, if it isn't supposed to return anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return village. Because function return type is `Village`.

```
        public static Village StandardVillage()
        {
            var randVillage = new Random();
            string name = GenerateCoolVillageName();
            var village = new Village( //make random village
                name: name,
                setLandscape: randVillage.Next(1, 5),
                setTool1: randVillage.Next(1, 3),
                setTool2: randVillage.Next(1, 3)
            );
            VisitedVillages.Add(village); //store village in ram so it can be revisited later
            VisitVillage(
                village.setLandscape,
                village.setTool1,
                village.setTool2
            );
            return village;
        }
```

If you don't want to return village, you can use `void`.

```
        public static void StandardVillage()
        {
            var randVillage = new Random();
            string name = GenerateCoolVillageName();
            var village = new Village( //make random village
                name: name,
                setLandscape: randVillage.Next(1, 5),
                setTool1: randVillage.Next(1, 3),
                setTool2: randVillage.Next(1, 3)
            );
            VisitedVillages.Add(village); //store village in ram so it can be revisited later
            VisitVillage(
                village.setLandscape,
                village.setTool1,
                village.setTool2
            );
        }
```